# Is DefaultListableBeanFactory expected to be a singleton in spring boot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot application, I am having multiple `@SpringBootTest`. I have set the `spring.test.context.cache.maxSize` to 1. It is working as expected and I observed from the logs that the context max size is 1.

```
24-03-05T12:29:03.643+05:30 DEBUG   --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@693c3e18 size = 1, maxSize = 1, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 16, missCount = 1]
```

But despite that, I am observing multiple `DefaultListableBeanFactory` in the heap dump?

[image]

All have the same reference path below

[image]

Is this expected or there are some known issues in the spring boot version I am using?

- spring-boot version - 3.1.7

Comment: It isn't as there could be other classes creating those internally as well. Check where they are coming from or what is holding them.

Comment: All have the same incoming references. I have updated the question with a screenshot. If I do not run the `@SpringBootTest` then I do not see `DefaultListableBeanFactory`. I can confirm that non Spring code is not doing this. But as per my understanding, I have set the context cache size to 1 so once the context gets removed `DefaultListableBeanFactory` should go away?

Comment: In theory yes, unless you introduced a memory leak which holds (directly or indirectly) a reference to the beanfactory. Then it will not be GC'ed and hang around.